# выбор из двумерного массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

есть массив `res[0]` типа

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["sub"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["order"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "new3"
    ["sub"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["order"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

и нужно получить значение ключа `name`.Как бы его не перебирал всегда получается `undefined`

Comment: res[0][0]['name']

Comment: у меня получается исходно `ok_array`. Я обрезаю через `split("_")`.В итоге консоль выводит этот самый `res[0]`в конце которого еще и `ok`, после закрывающей скобки массива. В таком случае как избавится от этого, т.к. пробовал и `res[0][0]['name']`, который так же `undefined`.Пробовал просто `split("ok_")` - результат тот же

Comment: вы привели массив php, как вы его отправляете на клиент, и что именно на клиенте получаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример [на jsbin](http://jsbin.com/badupiqime/edit?html,js,output)
Доступ к элементам проиходит либо через точку, либо через квадратные скобки.

```
var res = [];
res[0] = [{id:37, name: 'myname'},{id:48, name: 'myname2'}];
console.log(res[0][0].name);
//myname
console.log(res[0][1]['name']);
//myname2
```